# Adding three dots at the bottom of <p> tag when text overflows

Tags: css, overflow

This is my HTML code

```
 <section class="mammaliaSection">
            <p>ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXT</p>
    </section>
```

and this is my CSS code

```
#main section{
height:610px;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
position:relative;

}
 section p{
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
   width:325px;
   height:150px;
   font-size:36px;
   display:block;
   color:white;
   margin-left:15px;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
 }
```

I want to add "..." at the bottom of p tag

Like so
[image]

My code shows three dots at the first line because of white-space:nowrap. Tried white-space:pre-line, but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with only CSS. You must use some JS for that. Please take a look at a simple JQuery code for adding three dots at end of an paragraph.

```js
while ($('p').outerHeight() > $('.text-box').height()) {
    $('p').text(function (index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    });
}
```

```css
.text-box{
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-box">
<p>ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL ANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL TEXTANIMAL </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps